# Hooking to Send/Receive Sync event of Outlook Contacts

Tags: outlook, vsto, ms-office

How can I attach an event handler for `SendAndReceive` event of Contact folders/Contact Items in Outlook 2007 using VSTO AddIn? I tried using:

```
Application.ActiveExplorer().SyncObjects.ForEach
{
   SyncObject.SyncEnd += \\Do something
}
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried

```
Application.ActiveExplorer().SyncObjects.AppFolders.SyncEnd += \\EventHandler
```

This hooks on to send/receive of all default folders..

Answer (score 0):

Actually my need was a bit different but may be the same:
    I wanted to be notified of the changes of a folder (appointments in my case) after a send/receive.
My first thought (and I think you are on the same track) was to check for a send/receive event and maybe get some collection of items out of it or something similar, but no such thing is available. (as is also explained in [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b8454dd6-9815-4c8c-ae61-c34870ff3af6))

My second path came from the [following article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32763644/outlook-2007-addin-appo.aspx): I can register to the `Item_Add` and `Item_Change` (and even `Item_Removed`) event of a folder (whom are also triggered by the changes done by a send receive):

Some code:

```
// Get the folder calendar folder and subscribe to the events.
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.ItemAdd += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);
    Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.ItemChange += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(Items_ItemChange);
}

// Do something with it.
void Items_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
    logItem(Item, "Add");
}
void logItem(object Item, string Action)
{

    Outlook.AppointmentItem item = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

    File.AppendAllText(@"e:\log.txt", string.Format("Item {0}: {1}", Action, Item));

    if (item != null)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"e:\log.txt", " - Appointment: " + item.Subject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up the mail send/receive event and then check that the mail type is a ContactItem.  Here is an example of the Send event.

```
// hook up the event
this.Application.ItemSend += ThisApplication_SentMail;
```

then in your event handler you check the mail item type;

```
internal void ThisApplication_SentMail(object item, ref bool cancel)
{
    Outlook.ContactItem contactItem = item as Outlook.ContactItem;

    // mail message is not a ContactItem, so exit.
    if (contactItem == null) return;

    // do  whatever you need to here

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to trigger an event after a new email is received & after email sync so that I get a new email, or else I will not receive a new email attachment.

Below my solution may help you.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     this.Application.NewMail += Application_NewMail;
}
     
private void Application_NewMail()
{
_currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
_currentExplorer.Session.SyncObjects[1].SyncEnd += AppFolders_SyncEnd;
_currentExplorer.Session.SyncObjects[1].Start();            
}
    
private void AppFolders_SyncEnd()
{
//Your enter code here
}
```

Comment: Your code will not work. Or will work only sometimes, The object raising the events must be alive to be able to raise the events - you are setting event handlers on an implicit variable which will be release as soon as GC runs. Store SyncObject in a separate class member.